# TensorFlow + Batch Gradient Descent: 0% accuracy on each batch, but network converges?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm currently very much a beginner with TensorFlow and Deep Learning in general, and I was trying to make a pretty simple 2-layer neural network with the `ReLU` activation function for the hidden layer, and `softmax` for the output layer. In particular, I was training on the well-known notMNIST dataset, which has the exact same shape as MNIST but with more difficult examples. This was how I solved it (using TensorFlow `v1.0.0`):

```
batch_size = 128
hidden_nodes = 1024

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                    shape=(batch_size, image_size * image_size))
    tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))
    tf_valid_dataset = tf.constant(valid_dataset)
    tf_test_dataset = tf.constant(test_dataset)

    weights_ih = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, hidden_nodes]))
    biases_ih = tf.Variable(tf.ones([hidden_nodes])/10)
    weights_ho = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_nodes, num_labels]))
    biases_ho = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]))

    logits = tf.matmul(tf_train_dataset, weights_ih) + biases_ih
    hidden_layer_output = tf.nn.relu(logits)

    output = tf.matmul(hidden_layer_output, weights_ho) + biases_ho
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=output, labels=tf_train_labels))

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)

    train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(hidden_layer_output)
    valid_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(
        tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_valid_dataset, weights_ih) + biases_ih),
                   weights_ho) + biases_ho)
    test_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(
        tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(tf_test_dataset, weights_ih) + biases_ih),
                   weights_ho) + biases_ho)
```

With a simple runner in this fashion:

```
num_steps = 5000

def accuracy(predictions, labels):
    return (100.0 * np.sum(np.argmax(predictions, 1) == np.argmax(labels, 1)) / predictions.shape[0])

with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print("Initialized")
    for step in range(num_steps):
        offset = (step * batch_size) % (train_labels.shape[0] - batch_size)
        batch_data = train_dataset[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        batch_labels = train_labels[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]
        feed_dict = {tf_train_dataset: batch_data, tf_train_labels: batch_labels}
        _, l, predictions =\
            sess.run([optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
        if (step % 500 == 0):
            print("Minibatch loss at step %d: %f" % (step, l))
            print("Minibatch accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(predictions, batch_labels))
            print("Validation accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(valid_prediction.eval(),
                                                           valid_labels))
    print("Test accuracy: %.1f%%" % accuracy(test_prediction.eval(), test_labels))
```

I get these results:

```
Initialized
Minibatch loss at step 0: 281.805603
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 21.9%
Minibatch loss at step 500: 18.725670
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 81.0%
Minibatch loss at step 1000: 13.720121
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 81.2%
Minibatch loss at step 1500: 16.521467
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 81.3%
Minibatch loss at step 2000: 4.905802
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 80.7%
Minibatch loss at step 2500: 1.040669
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 82.4%
Minibatch loss at step 3000: 2.731811
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 80.6%
Minibatch loss at step 3500: 1.011298
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 81.9%
Minibatch loss at step 4000: 1.432833
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 82.7%
Minibatch loss at step 4500: 0.934623
Minibatch accuracy: 0.0%
Validation accuracy: 82.5%
Test accuracy: 89.6%
```

As can be seen, the minibatch accuracy is *always* `0%`, but the minibatch loss is going down and the validation accuracy is going up. It seems the model "works", but I think that something else is going on that's indicative of a larger problem. The sudden jump after 500 epochs is also suspicious. Since I don't have much intuition for this, I tried various superficial things like altering the learning rate and batch size, but they didn't do anything to that perpetual 0% accuracy.

It would be really appreciated if someone more experienced in TensorFlow can tell me what might be causing this, so I can learn to avoid it in the future.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(output)
```

instead of

```
train_prediction = tf.nn.softmax(hidden_layer_output)
```

and it should work.

By the way: I wouldn't call logit what you called logits. Your outputs would be called logits, but that's just a naming issue...

Comment: Gracious, this was the silliest mistake I could ever have made! Thanks so, so much.